# Git: How to change the contents of a tagged release?

Tags: git, github, release

I have a project on GitHub with a single branch (master) and multiple tagged releases.  When I attempt to build one of the older tagged releases, it will not build anymore with the latest version of the build tools.  I need to make a change to be compatible with the new build tools.  I know which source file is causing the failure and I know what change to make to the source file to make it build cleanly.  My question is about the mechanics of making the change to the git repo.  Is there a way to replace a file within a tagged release created months ago when the repo has since diverged in many ways?  Do I need to create a branch for the old release, or is there is a better way?

Comment: Are you using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) for your releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify a tagged version ever. Define in a readme which version of the build tool you are using is required for building the version and then use that version to build that version.

If you really need this, I would not recommend changing the tagged version, but either make a branch, or just some commit on top of the tag, tagged with a new name, that makes it compatible with the new build tool version.